# Algorithms or techniques for pattern recognition

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning, pattern-recognition

I am looking for algorithms or techniques that could be used for pattern recognition/extraction in data. Preferably I would like to know if there are any algorithm implementations in Python that I could study from. I am not really looking for novelty research but hands-on examples and implementations.

More specifically I would ideally like to develop an algorithm that could identify patterns (commonly repeated observations within a dataset) or trends in an unsupervised way, mostly in numeric data, not time series necessarily.

I am not sure if my understanding of pattern recognition is correct but an example of algorithms that could be used for my case I have found so far is Latent Dirichlet Allocation for text data and autoencoder neural networks for outlier detection.

Comment: Welcome to CV. An answer to your question would require more details on what kind of patterns you're looking for. Trends and patterns are what is searched for by any model or technique, be it supervised or unsupervised.